# Difference between v-on:click="..." and using onclick="..." in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

What is the difference between `v-on:click="..."` and using `onclick="..."` in Vue.js?

I understand that with the v-on:click you need to write the handler inside of the Vue object (like the [example in the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Method-Event-Handlers)), but what is the advantage? It seems simple enough to just write an `onclick="..."` to call function (outside of the Vue object).

Comment: @VicJordan No, it's not the same question.

Comment: @VicJordan unless I'm mistaken, the OP is asking about the difference between `v-on` and the native DOM API's `onclick`.  The post you linked is not about that.

Comment: @VicJordan I don't think its a duplicate, the referenced question explains the sytactic shorthand

Comment: Two reasons come to my mind: 1.) consistency - `v-on:` notation can be used not just for native DOM events but for application-defined vue events, thus you gain consistency. 2.) `v-on:` handlers can be defined not just on DOM nodes but on vue components.

Comment: @collapsar I think I'm starting to get it. You can handle special stuff such as v-on:click.self='...'. And all your functions will have to be defined within the Vue class, thus organization. Although wouldn't your Vue class become huge? Also, this section helped me understand a bit https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Why-Listeners-in-HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the chief differences is scope access.  `onclick`'s bound scope is global so the functions that you want it to call have to be accessible from the global scope.   `v-on`'s scope is the Vue model.

Another thing is that Vue provides a very easy API to define custom events through `vm.$emit()`.  It's also very easy to listen for those events using `v-on:customevent="callback"` which can be easily cognitively mapped to a hypothetical `onfizz="callback()"`.

With that in mind, it makes sense to also provide `v-on:click` for a consistent API as well as the other extensions `v-on` provides.

```js
/*
 * This pollutes scope.  You would have to start
 * making very verbose function names or namespace your 
 * callbacks so as not collide with other handlers that
 * you need throughout your application.
 */
function onClickGlobal() {
  console.log("global");
}

const fizzbuzz = {
  template: "<button @click='onClick'>FizzBuzz</button>",
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.$emit("fizz");
    }
  }
};

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    fizzbuzz
  },
  methods: {
    onClickModel() {
      console.log("model");
    },
    onFizz() {
      console.log("heard fizz");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <section>
    <h2>Buttons and Clicks</h2>

    <!-- Calling function of the bound scope -->
    <button @click="onClickModel">v-on Model</button>
    <!-- Works as well, but calls the global  -->
    <button @click="onClickGlobal">v-on Global</button>

    <!-- You need to explicitly invoke the function from onclick -->

    <!-- This won't work because onClickModel isn't global -->
    <button onclick="onClickModel()">onclick Model</button>
    <!-- Works because onClickGlobal is global -->
    <button onclick="onClickGlobal()">onclick Global</button>

    <!-- You can technically call onClickModel through the global app -->
    <!-- but you really shouldn't -->

    <!-- Works because app.onClickModel is technically global -->
    <button onclick="app.onClickModel()">onclick Global through app.onClickModel</button>

  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Custom Events</h2>
    <fizzbuzz @fizz="onFizz"></fizzbuzz>
    <!-- The element below doesn't work -->
    <button onfizz="onClickGlobal">Hypothetical Fizz</button>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer. One thing: `<button onclick="onClickGlobal">` doesn't actually work, because you need to explicitly invoke it like `onclick="onClickGlobal()"`. Vue will automatically invoke the function passed to an event listener, but `onclick` won't

Comment: Also, technically, you could call the `app` Vue instance's method using `onclick` like this `<button onclick="app.onClickModel()">onclick Model</button>`. Almost certainly bad practice unless you have a very unique use case, but just fyi

Comment: @thanksd You're right, I've updated the examples to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Its all about the scope. To answer your Question "but what is the advantage":

No benefit as long as you use it in a small frame for yourself. BUT as soon as you want to use it for example another project which has some JS-Components itself, you'd have to worry about colliding with some existing global functions. While having everything in the component itself you dont have to worry about a thing.